# Glimmer child component does not re-render when the parent passes it a different argument

Tags: glimmer.js

To be more explicit, the child component creates a property which is dependent on the argument passed by the parent component. *I am not using the parent argument directly in the child template (this case works just fine).*

Coming from a React background, my mental model suggests new arguments passed to a component will trigger re-render. But I am aware Glimmer does things differently with its `@tracked` decorator.

Okay, here is the contrived example. For a demo, head to the [Glimmer Playground](https://glimmer-playground.netlify.com/?app=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).

```html
// parent-template.hbs
<button onclick={{action doubleNumber}}>Double Number</button>
<div>
  Parent - {{number}}
</div>

<Child @number={{number}} />
```

```ts
// parent-component.ts
import Component, { tracked } from '@glimmer/component';

export default class extends Component {
  @tracked number = 2;

  doubleNumber() {
    this.number = this.number * 2;
  }
}
```

```html
// child-template.ts
<div>
  Child will render double of parent {{doubleOfParent}}
</div>
```

```ts
// child-component.ts
import Component, { tracked } from "@glimmer/component";

export default class extends Component {
  args: {
    number: number;
  }

  get doubleOfParent () {
    return 2 * this.args.number;
  }
};
```

Here the parent displays the doubled number on every click of the button. But the child never re-renders?

My question is do we always need to have the `tracked` variable inside the template. In this case `number`. And express the child template like this

```html
<div>
  Child will render double of parent {{double @number}}
</div>
```

Here `double` is helper which doubles the number.

If it is so what is the reason behind having the `tracked` properties/argument in the template?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your `doubleOfParent()` method is missing a `@tracked` annotation since its output depends on the `args` property:

```ts
import Component, { tracked } from "@glimmer/component";

export default class extends Component {
  args: {
    number: number;
  }

  @tracked('args')
  get doubleOfParent() {
    return 2 * this.args.number;
  }
};
```

you can find more information on this topic at https://glimmerjs.com/guides/tracked-properties