# How to set initial state of glimmer component based on argument?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, glimmer.js

I am struggling to figure out how to implement data down, actions up in a glimmer component hierarchy (using Ember Octane, v3.15).

I have a parent component with a list of items. When the user clicks on a button within the `Parent` component, I want to populate an `Editor` component with the data from the relevant item; when the user clicks "Save" within the `Editor` component, populate the changes back to the parent. Here's what happens instead:

[image: GIF of my app]

**How can I make the text box be populated with "Hello", and have changes persisted back to the list above when I click "Save"?**

### Code

```
{{!-- app/components/parent.hbs --}}
<ul>
{{#each this.models as |model|}}
    <li>{{model.text}} <button {{on 'click' (fn this.edit model)}}>Edit</button></li>
{{/each}}
</ul>

<Editor @currentModel={{this.currentModel}} @save={{this.save}} />
```

```js
// app/components/parent.js
import Component from '@glimmer/component';
export default class ParentComponent extends Component {
    @tracked models = [
        { id: 1, text: 'Hello'},
        { id: 2, text: 'World'}
    ]
    @tracked currentModel = null;

    @action
    edit(model) {
        this.currentModel = model;
    }

    @action
    save(model) {
        // persist data
        this.models = models.map( (m) => m.id == model.id ? model : m )
    }
}
```

```
{{!-- app/components/editor.hbs --}}
{{#if @currentModel}}
<small>Editing ID: {{this.id}}</small>
{{/if}}
<Input @value={{this.text}} />
<button {{on 'click' this.save}}>Save</button>
```

```js
// app/components/editor.hbs
import Component from '@glimmer/component';
import { tracked } from "@glimmer/tracking";
import { action } from "@ember/object";

export default class EditorComponent extends Component {
    @tracked text;
    @tracked id;

    constructor() {
        super(...arguments)
        if (this.args.currentModel) {
            this.text = this.args.currentModel.text;
            this.id = this.args.currentModel.id;
        }
        
    }

    @action
    save() {
        // persist the updated model back to the parent
        this.args.save({ id: this.id, text: this.text })
    }
}
```

### Rationale/Problem

I decided to implement `Editor` as a stateful component, because that seemed like the most idiomatic way to get form data out of the `<Input />` component. I set the initial state using `args`. Since `this.currentModel` is `@tracked` in `ParentComponent` and I would expect re-assignment of that property to update the `@currentModel` argument passed to `Editor`.

Indeed that seems to be the case, since clicking "Edit" next to one of the items in `ParentComponent` makes `<small>Editing ID: {{this.id}}</small>` appear. However, neither the value of the `<Input />` element nor the `id` are populated.

I understand that `this.text` and `this.id` are not being updated because the `constructor` of `EditorComponent` is not being re-run when `currentModel` changes in the parent... but I'm stuck on what to do instead.

---

### What I've tried

As I was trying to figure this out, I came across [this example](https://bloggr.exmer.com/authors/) ([code](https://github.com/broerse/ember-cli-blog)), which has pretty much the same interaction between `BlogAuthorComponent` ([hbs](https://github.com/broerse/ember-cli-blog/blob/master/app/components/blog-author.hbs)) and `BlogAuthorEditComponent` ([hbs](https://github.com/broerse/ember-cli-blog/blob/master/app/components/blog-author-edit.hbs), [js](https://github.com/broerse/ember-cli-blog/blob/master/app/components/blog-author-edit.js)). Their solution, as applied to my problem, would be to write EditorComponent like this:

```
{{!-- app/components/editor.hbs --}}
{{#if this.isEditing}}
<small>Editing ID: {{@currentModel.id}}</small>
<Input @value={{@currentModel.text}} />
<button {{on 'click' this.save}}>Save</button>
{{/if}}
```

```js
// app/components/editor.hbs
import Component from '@glimmer/component';
import { tracked } from "@glimmer/tracking";
import { action } from "@ember/object";

export default class EditorComponent extends Component {
    get isEditing() {
        return !!this.args.currentModel
    }

    @action
    save() {
        // persist the updated model back to the parent
        this.args.save({ id: this.id, text: this.text })
    }
}
```

[image]

It works! But I don't like this solution, for a few reasons:

- Modifying a property of something passed to the child component as an `arg` seems... spooky... I'm honestly not sure why it works at all (since while `ParentComponent#models` is `@tracked`, I wouldn't expect properties of POJOs  within that array to be followed...)
- This updates the text in `ParentComponent` as you type which, while neat, isn't what I want---I want the changes to be persisted only when the user clicks "Save" (which in this case does nothing)
- In my real app, when the user is not "editing" an existing item, I'd like the form to be an "Add Item" form, where clicking the "Save" button adds a new item. I'm not sure how to do this without duplicating the form and/or doing some hairly logic as to what goes in `<Input @value`...

I also came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48007635/glimmer-child-component-does-not-re-render-when-the-parent-passes-it-a-different), but it seems to refer to an old version of glimmer.

Thank you for reading this far---I would appreciate any advice!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To track changes to `currentModel` in your `editor` component and set a default value, use the `get` accessor:

```
get model() {
  return this.args.currentModel || { text: '', id: null };
}
```

And in your template do:

```
{{#if this.model.id}}
  <small>
    Editing ID:
    {{this.model.id}}
  </small>
{{/if}}
<Input @value={{this.model.text}} />
<button type="button" {{on "click" this.save}}>
  Save
</button>
```

Be aware though that this will mutate `currentModel` in your `parent` component, which I guess is not what you want. To circumvent this, create a new object from the properties of the model you're editing.

Solution:

```
// editor/component.js
export default class EditorComponent extends Component {
  get model() {
    return this.args.currentModel;
  }

  @action
  save() {
    this.args.save(this.model);
  }
}
```

In your parent component, create a new object from the passed model. Also, remember to reset `currentModel` in the save action. Now you can just check whether `id` is null or not in your `parent` component's `save` action, and if it is, just implement your `save` logic:

```
// parent/component.js
@tracked currentModel = {};

@action
edit(model) {
  // create a new object
  this.currentModel = { ...model };
}

@action
save(model) {
  if (model.id) {
    this.models = this.models.map((m) => (m.id == model.id ? model : m));
  } else {
    // save logic
  }

  this.currentModel = {};
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try this (and welcome to SO)! For the second solution, it feels weird for `get model` to have side effects (i.e. mutating `this.newModel`). The [Octane Upgrade guide refers to a similar situation](https://guides.emberjs.com/release/upgrading/current-edition/glimmer-components/#toc_updating-component-state) and recommends lifting the state to the parent component, which I guess would be like your first suggestion (or some combination, where `ParentComponent` maintains a version of `newModel`)

Comment: No problem. I've updated my answer not to have the potential of introducing side-effects in the editor component. Tbh, I'd probably go for an entirely different approach to achieve what you're looking for, e.g. conditionally creating the editor component based on some property in the parent component. I haven't given it too much thought though...